# Real time temperature and time display with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, tkinter-entry

I have this project with Raspberry Pi microcontroller in which I control a heating element depending on the temperature sensed by a type K thermocouple. Basically, when the temperature sensed is below a certain value, the heating element is activated, and when is above the electric current is interrupted and the heat is off.

The hardware went good and now I have the project implemented, but I want to make a step further and implement a GUI that displays the temperature sensed by the thermocouple in real time and display it with respect of the date and time of the measurement.

I am very new to this and I saw that Tkinter is a good options for beginners, but I can't figure it out how to change the label dynamically.

I know that there are questions related to this topic but I think I saw all of the answers and still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is what I have so far (it's something I found online and adjusted to my needs)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import urllib
import requests 
import time

import board
import psutil
import digitalio
import adafruit_max31856
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


Heat_PIN=24
temp = 0

# Create sensor object, communicating over the board's default SPI bus
spi = board.SPI()
# allocate a CS pin and set the direction
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
cs.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
# create a thermocouple object with the above
thermocouple = adafruit_max31856.MAX31856(spi, cs)
# We first check if a libgpiod process is running. If yes, we kill it!
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == 'libgpiod_pulsein' or proc.name() == 'libgpiod_pulsei':
        proc.kill()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(Heat_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
temp=thermocouple.temperature
GPIO.output(Heat_PIN, GPIO.LOW)


class Begueradj(tkinter.Frame):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def READ():

        cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
        cs.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
        spi = board.SPI() 
        thermocouple = adafruit_max31856.MAX31856(spi, cs)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(Heat_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
        temp=thermocouple.temperature
        GPIO.output(Heat_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  
        temp=thermocouple.temperature

    
    
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.parent.title("Canvas Test")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")


        # Define the different GUI widgets
        self.temp_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "Temperature:")
        self.temp_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.lbl = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = " ")
        self.lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.lbl.config(text=str(temp))
      
        
        self.date_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "Date Modified:")
        self.date_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.date_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.lbl_d = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = " ")
        self.lbl_d.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.W)
        self.lbl_d.config(text= time)
    

        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self.parent, columns=('Temperature', 'Modification date'))
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Temperature')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Modification Date')
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tkinter.YES)
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.treeview = self.tree
        # Initialize the counter
        self.i = str(temp)


    def insert_data(self):
        """
        Insertion method.
        """
        for l in range(10):
            time.sleep(3)
            print(str(temp))
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(temp), values=(self.lbl.get(), self.lbl_d.get()))
            self.treeview.update_idletasks() 
 # Increment counter
            self.i = self.i + 1

def main():
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Basically what I want to do with this code is to register the last measurement of temperature and the time of the measurement and then display them in the treeview. So far I only managed to make the window and to display the last temperature measurement, but it will update only if I close the window and open up again.

Maybe someone can help me with this matter.

Comment: This question is really too broad for a specific answer without having to re-write your code in it's entirety.  I suggest you start-out by separating the your code into two classes.  The first class deals with the interface with the thermo-couple and the heater, while the second class addresses the GUI.  Within the gui class you can interrogate the state or each display loop. In this way, the status will be constsantly updated.  For a good introduction on how best use tkinter see [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I put all my code lines in this question but I think the issue comes from how the widgets are defined. As far as I understood from what I have read . Thank you for the link, I will deffinitely give it a try.